# OpenSSL installed, but Ruby unable to require it

Tags: ruby, openssl, github

I'm trying to setup *github-pages* on my Ubuntu laptop, and following the guide provided by Github I have to install the *bundler* package; giving the command

```
~$ gem install bundler
```

returns me this error.

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources`

Then I have installed OpenSSL, launched the command to update software and stuff and tried again to install *bundler*, but the error kept showing.

How can I fix this? Is there any specific command to rebuild ruby making it aware about the fact that openSSL is now installed?

Comment: Which `openssl` package did you install? I believe you'll need the development package in order to build against it (part of the bundler build steps). Try `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`, try again and update your question. :)

Comment: I've installed it, but nothing changes! I'm aware of my newbieness, so probably there exists a simple way of solving this, but for the moment I'm stuck on this! The problem is likely to be in the way I'm upgrading Ruby, I think! Is there any specific command to rebuild Ruby?

Comment: Please **include in your question** all information on the Ruby specific changes you made to your system. The way Ruby is built may be very relevant to your issue now but we don't see that information currently.

Comment: I've figured out how to solve the problem (with huge luck) by myself, I will answer to my own question, anyway thanks :-) I will provide as many details as possible!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the answer to my own question, and I think it would be more clear to post as an answer, rather than editing the question.

**1<sup>st</sup> try. Let's go through the path of non-safe source link.**

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25186429), a possible choice to bypass the openSSL check is to remove the safe *https* link and add the non-safe one:

```
gem source -r https://rubygems.org/
gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
```

This way, the installation seems to go fine, but somewhere around the process openSSL is required again (for *nokogiri* gem, if I remember it well).

**2<sup>nd</sup> try. Rebuild Ruby (it was so easy).**

By the time I asked this question, my brain was probably not working properly. After installing openSSL by the usual way:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

I got to my ruby directory and typed the following lines:

```
pushd ext/openssl
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
popd
```

This way, I had all dependencies issues and stuff solved (I guess). Then, running

```
./configure
make
make install
```

I've rebuilt Ruby and finally the installation went fine.

Comment: I've tried your 2nd step but it failed. 1st one was still needed

Answer (score 4):

Rebuilding ruby after `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libreadline-dev libgdbm-dev` can solve this issue.

The solution is found here: http://www.larshaendler.com/2015/05/20/unable-to-require-openssl-install-openssl-and-rebuild-ruby-on-ubuntu-14-lts/

Comment: For me this answer worked an the accepted one did not. (on debian 8.9)